# pandas .sortlevel cant sort negative numbers

Tags: python, sorting, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that I constructed by reading in various CSV files. It looks like this:

```
ID                  V2        H1-b          V3          H2          V1        H1a
position         -50.0       600.0      -125.0      -720.0        23.0      450.0
2000-01-01   -1.057609    1.160002    1.082879   -1.304001   -0.259283   1.285260  
2000-02-01   -1.133474   -0.385869    0.756780    2.311465    1.060337  -1.059041  
2000-03-01    1.209086   -0.774133    0.018603    0.969665   -1.221080   1.717816  
...
```

When I try sorting it with `df_sort = df.sortlevel(level=1,axis=1)` (or `sortlevel='position'`, same result), I get the following result:

```
ID                  V3          V2          H2          V1        H1-a     H1-b 
position        -125.0       -50.0      -720.0        23.0       450.0    600.0 
2000-01-01    1.082879   -1.057609   -1.304001   -0.259283    1.285260    1.160002 
2000-02-01    0.756780   -1.133474    2.311465    1.060337   -1.059041   -0.385869 
2000-03-01    0.018603    1.209086    0.969665   -1.221080    1.717816   -0.774133
```

The positive Numbers are sorted the correct way (23<450<600), but the negative numbers are "random".

As far as I can tell, all my CSV files are the same (no spaces before the numbers or something), and all the entries in the dataframe are produced by the same script.

But when I tried to see if I can reproduce that with a simple synthetic dataframe, sorting works:

```
header=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[-3,-300,4,100,34,-324],['s']],names=['loc','X'])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 6), index=['a','b','c','d','e'], columns = header)
```

results in

```
In [6]: df.head()
Out[6]: 
loc      -3        -300       4         100       34       -324
S           s         s         s         s         s         s
a   -0.444521 -0.616153  2.261075 -1.857406  0.367582  1.212705
b   -1.389062 -0.741163  0.512457  1.013495 -2.003147  0.651232
c   -0.376925 -0.271408 -0.854247  0.355438 -0.791896 -1.359056
d   -2.929450  0.228446  1.287110 -1.117579 -0.501250  1.340859
e   -0.653089  0.245901  0.036066  0.776839 -1.112828 -0.476782

In [9]: df_sort = df.sortlevel('loc',axis=1)

In [10]: df_sort.head()
Out[10]: 
loc      -324      -300      -3         4         34        100
S           s         s         s         s         s         s
a    1.212705 -0.616153 -0.444521  2.261075  0.367582 -1.857406
b    0.651232 -0.741163 -1.389062  0.512457 -2.003147  1.013495
c   -1.359056 -0.271408 -0.376925 -0.854247 -0.791896  0.355438
d    1.340859  0.228446 -2.929450  1.287110 -0.501250 -1.117579
e   -0.476782  0.245901 -0.653089  0.036066 -1.112828  0.776839
```

as does `sortlevel(level = 0`

First idea was that the the other things in my index disturb the sorting, but `df_sort = df_GW.sortlevel(level='location',axis=1,sort_remaining=False)` does not change anything in the sorting.

What am I doing wrong?

I suspect that for whatever reason something gets treated as a string or something, but I can't find any indication for that.

**EDIT**
output of `df.dtypes`:
real df:

```
In [29]: df_GW.dtypes
Out[29]: 
ID     Position  
V2     -50.0     float64
H1-b   600.0     float64
V3     -125.0    float64
H2     -720.0    float64
V1     23.0      float64
H1-a   450.0     float64
dtype: object
```

synthetic:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'dtype'
```

`df.columns`
real:

```
 MultiIndex(levels=[[u'H1-a', u'H1-b', u'H2', u'V1', u'V2', u'V3'], [u'-125.0', u'-50.0', u'-720.0', u'23.0', u'450.0', u'600.0']],
       labels=[[4, 1, 5, 2, 3, 0], [1, 5, 0, 2, 3, 4], [4, 1, 5, 2, 3, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], #not sure what's happening here. The original df is a bit bigger, and I'm cutting it to size
       names=[u'ID', u'position'])
```

synthetic:

```
 MultiIndex(levels=[[-720.0, -125.0, -50.0, 23.0, 450.0, 600.0], [u's']],
       labels=[[2, 5, 1, 0, 3, 4], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],
       names=[u'loc', u'S'])
```

Comment: what is the output of `df.dtypes`?

Comment: with the real and synthetic data I get an error `'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'types'`.

Comment: what return `df.columns`?

Comment: Yeah, because you want **d**types

Comment: If you showed us the output of `df.dtypes` we could figure out if your columns are character, not integer/numeric

Comment: you are clearly doing something wrong. All `DataFrames` have a `dtypes` attribute. Check again.

Comment: synthetic data dtypes: `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'dtype'`; real data: `name     location  number  datatype   
Valley2  -50.0     3460.0  Groundwater    float64
Hill1-b  600.0     3457.0  Groundwater    float64
Valley3  -125.0    3461.0  Groundwater    float64
Hill2    -720.0    3458.0  Groundwater    float64
Valley1  23.0      3459.0  Groundwater    float64
Hill1-a  450.0     3456.0  Groundwater    float64
dtype: object
` probably hard to read in comment? I'll edit into the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is problem types of numbers in first level of `MultiIndex` are not `float`, but `string`:

```
np.random.seed(0)
header=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['-125','-50','4','100','34','-720'],
                                   ['s']],names=['loc','X'])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 6), index=['a','b','c','d','e'], columns = header)
print (df)
loc      -125       -50         4       100        34      -720
X           s         s         s         s         s         s
a    1.764052  0.400157  0.978738  2.240893  1.867558 -0.977278
b    0.950088 -0.151357 -0.103219  0.410599  0.144044  1.454274
c    0.761038  0.121675  0.443863  0.333674  1.494079 -0.205158
d    0.313068 -0.854096 -2.552990  0.653619  0.864436 -0.742165
e    2.269755 -1.454366  0.045759 -0.187184  1.532779  1.469359

df.sortlevel('loc',axis=1, inplace=True)
print (df)
loc      -125       -50      -720       100        34         4
X           s         s         s         s         s         s
a    1.764052  0.400157 -0.977278  2.240893  1.867558  0.978738
b    0.950088 -0.151357  1.454274  0.410599  0.144044 -0.103219
c    0.761038  0.121675 -0.205158  0.333674  1.494079  0.443863
d    0.313068 -0.854096 -0.742165  0.653619  0.864436 -2.552990
e    2.269755 -1.454366  1.469359 -0.187184  1.532779  0.045759
```

If need cast `string` level to `float`, need change values and assign to new column names:

```
#change multiindex
cols = list(zip(df.columns.get_level_values('loc').astype(float),
                df.columns.get_level_values('X')))
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(cols, names = df.columns.names)


df.sortlevel('loc',axis=1, inplace=True)
print (df)
loc      -720      -125      -50        4         34        100
X           s         s         s         s         s         s
a   -0.977278  1.764052  0.400157  0.978738  1.867558  2.240893
b    1.454274  0.950088 -0.151357 -0.103219  0.144044  0.410599
c   -0.205158  0.761038  0.121675  0.443863  1.494079  0.333674
d   -0.742165  0.313068 -0.854096 -2.552990  0.864436  0.653619
e    1.469359  2.269755 -1.454366  0.045759  1.532779 -0.187184
```

Comment: Seems to be the case. I guess the `u'-50.0',...` I get from `df.columns` are pointing in that direction. That means something is wrong with the stuff that is constructing the dataframe. As a quick hack, is there a way to turn an index from string to float (or integer)?

Answer (score 0):

Try `df.sort_values(by=[1], axis=0, ascending=True)` where [1] is your column of values.

Comment: I am trying to sort in my rows, not in my columns.